# sending json data from rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a rails form, which has some fields.

Now i want to send values of these fields, converted to json to some url

I can traverse through each element of form, convert it into json(using javascript)
prepare a json string and send a request to the server.[client side conversion]

Other approach can be, posting the form normally to some controller action. then reading the data on the rails controller. parsing it to json and sending to desired url[server side conversion]

But i dont think these are good approaches.

what can be better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to convert before sending to the server? You can easily generate JSON in Rails on the server side using the submitted POST data.

Comment: U mean using to_json against, every param string on the server side? can u show some example.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: please find creating an issue @ http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues i am trying to accomplish the same